# Salesforce Canvas App equivalent on MS Dynamics

Tags: canvas, salesforce, dynamics-crm

What is the best option to embed / IFrame a web application in MS Dynamics CRM like a canvas app in Salesforce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design an HTML web resource and add it to a CRM form. For more information take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx).

Comment: This seems to be for coding web applications inside the CRM. I am looking for a simple usecase like a web tab where I can open an external web app from inside the CRM. Eg: I want to add a menu item clicking on which opens this web app (say gmail) inside the CRM.

Comment: Still this is the way to go. Actually most applications of HTML web resources in Dynamics CRM are about adding small UI elements to web pages.